# Waiting to recv() on two Websockets

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to create essentially a websocket-to-websocket bridge/gateway. This server should accept public connections on 8765 and forwards messages to another internal server waiting on 7777, and vice versa.

My question is how do I monitor for arriving messages from *either* socket? The code below is only looping over the public socket messages. I'm not sure how to be watching both the publicsock and publicsock.privatesock at the same time. If something happens on either socket, I need to forward the message to the other side.

Originally from http://aaugustin.github.io/websockets/

```
import asyncio
import websockets

@asyncio.coroutine
def handler(publicsock, path):
    publicsock.privatesock = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:7777/')
    while True:
        message = yield from publicsock.recv()
        if message is None:
            break
        yield from processPublicMessage(publicsock, message)
    publicsock.privatesock.close()

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Maybe you could use threading? e.g., `server_t1 = threading.Thread(target=start_server)` and then server_t1.start() then just repeat for the second server? That way *maybe* python fires both up and they can both run their respective handle functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with `FIRST_COMPLETED` to wait on both future results.